MongoDB - conditional uniqueness constraints on different "id" fields
I have a requirement to enforce uniqueness in documents in a MongoDB collection.
My documents have an "id" field and a "name" field, and several other fields. The "id" field is NOT unique.
My requirement is such that the "name" should be unique across different values of "id". However, there can be multiple documents with the same "id" and same "name". (There can be multiple "name"s in the same "id").
For example:
Following documents are allowed (same id, same/different names):
{ "id" : "1", "name": "Alice"}  
{ "id" : "1", "name": "Bob"}  
{ "id" : "1", "name": "Alice"}

However following are not allowed (same name, different ids):
{ "id" : "1", "name": "Alice"}  
{ "id" : "2", "name": "Alice"}

Is there anyway possible to enforce this on the database itself, and not in application logic?

Why have you tagged both CosmosDB and MongoDB? Should you have tagged azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi? Is that what you are actually using?

Yes thats is what I am using. Thanks for pointing it out - I did not see that tag listed. Since I am able to use most of MongoDB documentation as is, I tagged it with mongo-db.

I think there is no way to "enforce" the rule with existing data by only database means. You may need to do a one-time clean-up if you have data that violates the rule. However, for newly inserted documents, you can do the following in aggregation and merge them into the collection.

$unionWith the new documents you wanted to insert(by putting them in $documents
$setWindowFields to compute the $denseRank within the partition name and by the order of id

For case 1, if they have different names, they will both have rank: 1
For case 2, if they have the same name and the same id, they will both have rank: 1
For case 3, if they have same name but different id, the new document will have rank > 1


$match to select only the documents with rank: 1
(cosmetics) $unset the rank field
$merge into the collection

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$documents": [
            // documents to be inserted here
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Alice"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$name",
      "sortBy": {
        "id": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "idRankInName": {
          "$denseRank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "idRankInName": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "idRankInName"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground for cases 1 and 2
Mongo Playground for case 3

Thanks for the response. It makes sense to me. I believe in "coll": "collection", we are taking the existing documents in the collection in account? Also, with this somebody can still write code to insert documents without this logic. Is it possible to have this logic run somehow every time documents get added to this collection?

@ksceriath As I mentioned, I don't think there is a way to enforce the rule for every insertion through only database means. Actually, I have considered triggers and change streams, but they involve a certain degree of application code. I suggest that you use the above solution as the only way of insertion if possible. For example, you might wrap that as a single insertion API and expose that as only mean to insert data into the database.

@ksceriath and about "coll": "collection", yes, just replace it with your collection name.
